# How can I solve for current opacity in this animation?

Tags: algorithm, function, math, lua

I'm trying to do a simple fade in/out animation in Lua.

I feel like these variables should be enough to solve for the alpha/opacity I want to set the box at every frame, but I'm having a lot of trouble with the fade out, since `alpha = targetAlpha * animationPos` always returns 0 while multiplying by the target alpha of 0.

All of these variables are decimal values between 0-1, representing alpha or %time completed.

1. `targetAlpha` - The alpha value at the end of animation.
2. `initialAlpha` - The alpha the box started at when the animation initialized.
3. `animationPos` - The current position (%time completed) of the animation
4. `currentAlpha` - Current alpha of the box.

Maybe I'm just super fried today, but I've been trying what feels like a billion combinations of these vars to find the equation that works, and to no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), which takes two values `a` and `b`, and an interpolation value `f` between 0 and 1.

```lua
function lerp(a, b, f)
    return a * (1 - f) + b * f
end
```

And now you can just interpolate between initial and target alpha using your current animation progress:

```lua
alpha = lerp(initialAlpha, targetAlpha, animationPos)
```